# How to convert special characters of an url in cakephp3?

Tags: url, cakephp-3.0

I have an upload folder in webroot that contains my pictures. And I read picture path from database.

```
picture->path = 'uploads\pictures\pic1.png'
```

When I try to show pictures with line below

```
echo $this->Html->image('/'.$picture->path);
```

browser could not show pictures. This is the result html that generated with cakephp

```
<img src="/projects/bookmarker/uploads%5Cpictures%5Cpic1.png" alt="">
```

I think special characters such as %5C caused this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
picture->path = 'uploads\pictures\pic1.png'
```

with

```
picture->path -- 'uploads/pictures/pic1.png'
```

The above can be achieved with  `str_replace()` in php.

Comment: This is not a solution for my question. Also in cakephp directory separator (DS) generated automatically

Comment: @anghazighermezi While the answer could be better, this actually _is_ the solution, while backward slashes might be valid in your OS filesystem, URLs _must_ use forward slashes, so you _must_ convert your path fragments accordingly before using them in a URL. I'd probably use a [**virtual property**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties) that returns the path in a URL compatible fashion.

Comment: Excuse me guys, And thank you. You are right. I thought special chars caused this problem :)